# Using javascript regexp to find the first AND longest match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegExp like the following simplified example:

```
var exp = /he|hell/;
```

When I run it on a string it will give me the first match, fx:

```
var str = "hello world";
var match = exp.exec(str);
// match contains ["he"];
```

**I want the first and longest possible match**,
and by that i mean sorted by index, then length.

Since the expression is combined from an array of RegExp's, I am looking for a way to find the longest match without having to rewrite the regular expression.

Is that even possible?

If it isn't, I am looking for a way to easily analyze the expression, and arrange it in the proper order. But I can't figure out how since the expressions could be a lot more complex, fx:

```
var exp = /h..|hel*/
```

Comment: Your second example would be a lot more interesting if it were for example: `/h....|hel*/`

Comment: It looks the same to me. I actually wanted to illustrate that the longest regexp was not necessarily the longest match. My simple expression should have been something like `/h.*?|hello/`. But i guess the users of this site knows what I mean anyway. At least you did :-)

Comment: If variable-width lookbehind assertions were possible in javascript (as they are for example in .NET and JGsoft regex flavours) you could achieve it this way: `exp = /.*(?<=h..|hel*)/ `. But so far this feature is not expected in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All regex implementations I know of will (try to) match characters/patterns from left to right and terminate whenever they find an over-all match.

In other words: if you want to make sure you get the longest possible match, you'll need to try all your patterns (separately), store all matches and then get the longest match from all possible matches.

Comment: I know. I edited the question. Thanks for the answer. I will start by finding the index of the first match, and then ad the ^ to each RegExp and search the substring starting from first index, since looking for expressions that aren't there, requres running through all the text.

Answer (score 5):

How about `/hell|he/` ?

Comment: It is not always as obvious as in this example.

Comment: Simple but devastating. :)

Comment: This helped me. I can sort the order of my or clauses. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it. It's explained here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

(In summary, change the operand order or group with question mark the second part of the search.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do *"longest match"* (or anything involving counting, minus look-aheads) with regular expressions.

Your best bet is to find **all** matches, and simply compare the lengths in the program.

Comment: By finding all matches you mean taking the regex apart at | and looking for each part individually? (Thus instead of looking for (a|(b(c|d)), one would have to look for 3 expressions: a, bc, bd. I wonder if one has to take optionality into account as well).  

Or is there some support for finding all matches?

Comment: @Jirka-x1: There is support for finding the *next* match; I simply meant write a loop that goes through every match and keeps track of which is longest.

Comment: I am not sure about javascript, but in Java, your approach does not work. 


`Matcher m = Pattern.compile("he|hell").matcher("hello world");        
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}`
 
produces a single result: 'he'. Second and subsequent invocations of find() start at the first character not matched by the previous invocation.

Comment: See my example above (I pressed enter too quickly)

Comment: @Jirka: If you want to match the longer if possible, use the regular expression `he(ll)?`

Comment: Yes, but then you must somehow compile the input regex into one that matches the longest possible string. Apart from simple examples such as this, this is hard. Not even sure if it is always possible (assuming one uses the usual perl style of regexes, not just simple regular expressions equivalent to finite state automata).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for (Considering this question is almost 8 years old...), but here's my grain of salt:

(Switching the he for hell will perform the search based on the biggest first)

```
var exp = /hell|he/;
var str = "hello world";
var match = exp.exec(str);

if(match)
{
  match.sort(function(a, b){return b.length - a.length;});            
  console.log(match[0]);
 }
```

Where match[0] is going to be the longest of all the strings matched.