# + is supposed to be greedy, so why am I getting a lazy result?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Why does the following regex return `101` instead of `1001`?

```js
console.log(new RegExp(/1(0+)1/).exec('101001')[0]);
```

I thought that `+` was greedy, so the longer of the two matches should be returned.

IMO this is different from [Using javascript regexp to find the first AND longest match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109684/using-javascript-regexp-to-find-the-first-and-longest-match) because I don't care about the first, just the longest.  Can someone correct my definition of greedy?  For example, what is the difference between the above snippet and the classic "oops, too greedy" example of `new RegExp(/<(.+)>/).exec('<b>a</b>')[0]` giving `b>a</b`?

(Note: This seems to be language-agnostic (it also happens in Perl), but just for ease of running it in-browser I've used JavaScript here.)

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool to extract the longest match. You might get all the substrings, test with `^10+1$` pattern and get the longest one using the language specific means.

Comment: use `/1(0+)1/` regex on match function and find the longest match by applying length function on the result.

Comment: `+` is greedy, but it will take the first match, and the middle  `1` is included in the first match, so it wouldn't be included in future matches and the `1001`  won't ever be matched.

Comment: @muru What's the difference between this and the classic HTML tag example `<.+>`?

Comment: The terminal characters are different. `<foo>` is a different case from, say `<foo<bar<blah<`

Comment: @muru `new RegExp(/<(.+)</,'g').exec('<b<a</b<')[0]` still gives `b<a</b`, though...is it the `.` that makes `+` extra greedy, or something?  Why doesn't that one stop at `b`?

Comment: Greedy means *up to the rightmost occurrence*, it never means the *longest in the input string*. If you see such an explanation, know it is wrong. Still, since the string is parsed from left to right, `101` will get matched in `101001` and the rest (`001`) just does not match (the matches are overlapping). You might use `(?=(10+1)).` and then check the length of each Group 1 value to get the longest one.

Comment: Indeed, this is not a duplicate. This question asks to get the longest match. The question it's closed as a duplicate of asks to get the first match, and in case of a tie, the longest match. They're not the same thing, and the question should not have been closed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that doesn't seem to hold true though, e.g. `new RegExp(/1(0+)1/).exec('1011001')[0]` gives `101` still instead of `1001` even though there is no overlap because of the extra 1.

Comment: @Kev O.o for me, it gives the entire string. For a comparable regexp to `1(0+)1`, try `<[^<]+<`.

Comment: @Kev with `1011001`, `1001` will be second match, since `101` was matched first going left to right.

Comment: @Kev:  And it is correct output because `exec` only returns 1 match. To get multiple matches, you need to use `exec` inside a loop checking if there is a match.

Comment: @muru sorry my bad, I had the wrong subscript in there.  You're right.  But still, it gives a longer result than `b`, that is what I meant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah!  OK, this combined with the other suggestions helps it make sense for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greedy means *up to the rightmost occurrence*, it never means the *longest in the input string*.

Regex itself is not the correct tool to extract the longest match. You might get all the substrings that match your pattern, and get the longest one using the language specific means.

Since the string is parsed from left to right, `101` will get matched in `101001` first, and the rest (`001`) will not match (as the `101` and `1001` matches are *overlapping*). You might use `/(?=(10+1))./g` and then check the length of each Group 1 value to get the longest one.

```js
var regex = /(?=(10+1))./g;
var str = "101001";
var m, res=[];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res); // => ["101", "1001"]

if (res.length>0) {
  console.log("The longest match:", res.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0]);
} // => 1001
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex always reads from left to right!  It will not look for something longer.  In the case of multiple matches, you have to re-execute the regex to get them, and compare their lengths yourself.

Comment: Can you provide a better definition of 'greedy' then?  (Doesn't it mean, find the longest?)

Comment: greedy means that it matches as much as possible. For example: your string "101001". if you use this regex `1.+1` it would match all, because it is greedy. But if you use this regex `1.+?1` it is not greedy and would only match "101" (see https://regex101.com/r/GeDOZL/1). I hope my explanation is clear

Comment: Right, so isn't the string that matches `1(0+)1` as much as possible `1001`, not `101`?

Comment: no, because regex reads from left to right and it will take the FIRST match. `101` already matches see https://regex101.com/r/giYk8A/1

Comment: And as @muru already said, regex does not go back: meaning when 101 is already match, it is "consumed" so only `001` is left.